Why docker network hosts can't be reached?
in my projects I have some backend services and 1 frontend service. I created dockerfiles, built images, created docker network  and I set up containers using docker-compose. here is my compose config:
version: '3.8'

services:
  service1-mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: service1-mongo
    ports:
      - "27001:27017" 
    volumes:
      - service1-mongo-data:/data/db
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.2

  service2-mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: service2-mongo
    ports:
      - "27002:27017" 
    volumes:
      - service2-mongo-data:/data/db
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.3

  service1:
    image: service1:latest
    container_name: service1
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://service1-mongo:27017/db02
    depends_on:
      - service1-mongo
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.4

  service2:
    image: service2:latest
    container_name: service2
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://service2-mongo:27017/iAutoService01
    depends_on:
      - service2-mongo
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.5

  app_frontend:
    image: app_frontend:latest
    container_name: app_frontend
    ports:
      - "3001:80" # Map port 3001 on host to port 80 on container
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.6

volumes:
  service1-mongo-data:
  service2-mongo-data:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: dev-network

after running compose,service1 and service2 connect to mongos and perform migrations, its ok.after I'm trying to ping service1 using host: service1:8083/api/v1/auth but I get Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND service1, also I'm trying to call 172.20.1.4:8083/api/v1/auth and getting timeout error. then I tried to call localhost:8083/api/v1/auth and it works. I'm confused - why docker network host dont work and how postman finds service in docker container on localhost? how its possible? also when I use frontend container and it performs requests to backend containers, there works only localhost and throws cors error.. what I'm doing wrong?

If you delete all the network configuration (the fixed IP, the external network, even the custom network name) does it work to access the services by service name?

@BMitch I started with that. without creating networks and could not use container names. one thing I notced-during docker-compose up it creates default network, though I removed network and ips from compose file, thats weird

Are you giving the containers time to start? What does "could not use container names" mean? Why couldn't you use them, what prevented it?

It sounds like the cases where the container names aren't working might be calls that originate from outside Docker (from Postman, from an application running in a browser).  Does that match what you're seeing?

First, I would create two different networks, one for each service and comment out IP numbers. Second, why are you exposing databases ports outside of Docker's network?

@BMitch I mean I cant use container name as hosts. when I call containerized backend service using its name as host, I get not found error.

@DavidMaze ok, maybe I understand something incorrect, but every container has its own ip, also I expose application port. so as I suppose if I use this ip+port, then I can reach my application in container, isnt it? according documentation instead of ip, can be used container name also. none of these ways works. only when I use localhost I can reach containers

You can't reach the container-private IP addresses or use any other Docker networking features from outside of Docker.
